# Getting class name as a string in static method in C++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, clang, c++14, static-methods

Assume we are working with Clang strictly. No other compiler is being used. Also note that Clang supports CXX ABI.

We are using C++14.

Normally, we would get demangled class name like so:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>

class GoodClass {
public:
    virtual const char *foo() const noexcept;
}

const char *
GoodClass::foo() const noexcept
{
    //  Naive implementation, not gonna' check any errors and stuff.
    int32_t status = 0;

    return abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(*this).name(), 0, 0, &status);
}
```

This method will help us when we need class names of public subclasses of this class:

```
class SomeSubclassOfGoodClass : public GoodClass { }

SomeSubclassOfGoodClass object;
std::cout << object.foo(); //  prints "SomeSubclassOfGoodClass"
```

However, in static methods, we could not use `this` since there is no instance. Therefore, it is impossible to serve an object to the `typeid` directive.

The examplary method serves well (with polymorphism), however it needs an instance to operate. This would involve problems about OO (such as constructors).

What would you do in a situation like this?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @Peter Same thing as foo().

Comment: Then construct a temporary instance of the required type, and call its `foo()`.

Comment: @Peter In OOP, sometimes you could not create temporary instances of a type, because construction may not be an idempotent operation. What's more to say, you are stating obvious. Please read the question first.

Comment: You're missing the 'clang' tag, I think.

Comment: @kfsone Indeed, thank you.

Comment: I did read the question, Leviathalon.   For a static function to return information like you seek, there is no alternative other than accessing an existing object of that type (either created locally, or accessed by some other means) and/or hard-coding some specific assumption about the type into the function.     You're asking for a third option, which simply does not exist.    Your wishing for it to exist does not make it so.

Comment: @Peter I do not wish anything to exist. What I ask is what a typical implementation in C++, where it would be in a language like C#, Swift, Objective-C or Java. The solutions we found until now are unsatisfying. If you know anything better, say it. Else you may tell there is no other solution. You cannot know everything, so you could not answer.

Comment: @Leviathlon: The .NET framework has no way to return polymorphic type information from a static class member. I have no idea what that should be anyway, or why you believe this to be useful.

Comment: @IInspectable .NET is not a language so far. I think you mean C#. Please tell me, how could you create an API controller class without fetching its name? Two ways: Class registration or run-time type introspection (based on reflection and/or compiler ABI). Class registration is an old-school way to do and not being used by .NET (namely Dropwizard uses this). Hence, ...

Comment: Splitting hairs, eh? I worded it the way I did to mean: No language targeting the .NET framework can deduce the dynamic type from a static class member. Considering that it can be invoked without even having an object, what should the dynamic type be then? This question really doesn't make sense, sorry.

Comment: @IInspectable Invoked object, maybe?

Comment: What object are you talking about, when calling `X::foo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of demangle needs a little work. At the moment you have a memory leak.

Here's one way to solve that:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdexcept>

struct demangled_string
{
    using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>;
    demangled_string(ptr_type&& ptr) noexcept;
    const char* c_str() const;
    operator std::string() const;

    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const;
private:
    ptr_type _ptr;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const demangled_string& str)
{
    return str.write(os);
}

inline std::string operator+ (std::string l, const demangled_string& r) {
    return l + r.c_str();
}

inline std::string operator+(const demangled_string& l, const std::string& r)
{
    return std::string(l) + r;
}

demangled_string demangle(const char* name);
demangled_string demangle(const std::type_info& type);
demangled_string demangle(std::type_index type);

template<class T>
demangled_string demangle(T* p) {
    return demangle(typeid(*p));
}

template<class T>
demangled_string demangle()
{
    return demangle(typeid(T));
}


// implementation

demangled_string::demangled_string(ptr_type&& ptr) noexcept
: _ptr(std::move(ptr))
{}

std::ostream& demangled_string::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
    if (_ptr) {
        return os << _ptr.get();
    }
    else {
        return os << "{nullptr}";
    }
}

const char* demangled_string::c_str() const
{
    if (!_ptr)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("demangled_string - zombie object");
    }
    else {
        return _ptr.get();
    }
}

demangled_string::operator std::string() const {
    return std::string(c_str());
}


demangled_string demangle(const char* name)
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    int status = -4;

    demangled_string::ptr_type ptr {
        abi::__cxa_demangle(name, nullptr, nullptr, &status),
        std::free
    };

    if (status == 0) return { std::move(ptr) };

    switch(status)
    {
        case -1: throw std::bad_alloc();
        case -2: {
            std::string msg = "invalid mangled name~";
            msg += name;
            auto p = (char*)std::malloc(msg.length() + 1);
            strcpy(p, msg.c_str());
            return demangled_string::ptr_type { p, std::free };
        }
        case -3:
            assert(!"invalid argument sent to __cxa_demangle");
            throw std::logic_error("invalid argument sent to __cxa_demangle");
        default:
            assert(!"PANIC! unexpected return value");
            throw std::logic_error("PANIC! unexpected return value");
    }
}

demangled_string demangle(const std::type_info& type)
{
    return demangle(type.name());
}

demangled_string demangle(std::type_index type)
{
    return demangle(type.name());
}

std::string method(const demangled_string& cls, const char* method)
{
    return std::string(cls) + "::" + method;
}

// test

class test_class
{
    using this_class = test_class;

    static auto classname() { return demangle<this_class>(); }

public:
    static void test1() {
        std::cout << method(demangle<this_class>(), __func__) << std::endl;
        std::cout << method(classname(), __func__) << std::endl;
    }

    void test2() {
        std::cout << method(demangle(this), __func__) << std::endl;
        std::cout << method(classname(), __func__) << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    test_class t;
    t.test1();
    t.test2();
}
```

expected output:

```
test_class::test1
test_class::test1
test_class::test2
test_class::test2
```

Answer (score 1):

The `typeid` operator may also be applied to a type, not just an expression: `typeid(GoodClass)` ought to work when you cannot access `this`.

Edit: without an instance you need to turn to static polymorphism. You could have a mix in base class `Identifiable<X>` which has a static method with the code you suggested above, but using `typeid(X)` instead. Your classes need to extend this class passing themselves as the template parameter (the curiously recursive template pattern), but it is not possible to ensure that a class does so:

```
class C : public Identifiable<C> {}; // method returns C
class D : public Identifiable<C> {}; // also returns C
```

Comment: Exactly, however we need polymorphism here. So your implementation suggestion won't give us the subclass name. It will only give the implementation class, which is `GoodClass` here. We should supply some class placeholder to the `typeid`, hence it will give us class name.

Comment: Also, another implementation would be appreciated too.

Comment: Static methods don't have an instance for you to discover the class name... The best you can do is either make it an instance method or put the static method in a mixin template base class following the CRTP: `class X : public Identifiable<X>` where the base class uses `typeid(X)`

Comment: @JavierMartín This was also on my mind. However, in a framework design, that could be misused. I think we're on the bounds of C++'s OO capabilities.

Comment: @Leviathlon in C++, everything can be misused. Like the other commenter, I don't see the use of typing Subclass::foo() just to get the string "Subclass" back. Without a polymorphic instance, I does not make sense to me. If you're thinking of using this for a plugin architecture, are you sure you're not better off having a XFactory  with some registry that subclasses of X need to use?